# How to dynamically pass contextual filter to a block view without changing view settings

Tags: views, blocks

I have a content type called artists. In various locations I want to feature one of the artists. I have a view block that has a contextual filter for the node id.

I want to display this this block on various locations of the website. I want site admins to be able to change the featured artist ( node id ) but I don't want them to have access to the views interface ) how can I pass the the node id via the blocks interface or is there some other way that I can make a mini admin screen that will let site admins choose the featured artist?

I don't want to use the promoted to homepage feature on the content type or any other field on the content type as the artist themselves have access to edit their content.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have a task:

> " I want site admins to be able to change the featured artist ( node id ) but I don't want them to have access to the views interface )"

and it seems you already decided to use specific solution:

> pass the the node id via the blocks interface

Don't do that. That's pretty weird and unneeded. Easier options are:

- Draggable Views and show only first one
- Use "sticky" or some other field to mark promoted artists (random order, limit 1 in case more than one is selected)